# Display Images on HTML using MongoDB, But it didn't show

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

I have the code backend using Node.js and Front end in HTML. I tried to get the image stored in mongo to front end. But in HTML it doesn't shows the image. But when I paste the binary data of image in img src tag it works. Help plz.

index.js

```
 function loadImages() {
    let isbn=''
    let imgSource=''
    if (CURRENT_URL.includes('#')) {
         isbn = CURRENT_URL.substr(CURRENT_URL.indexOf('#') + 1, 
  CURRENT_URL.length);
        console.log(isbn);
    }

    axios.get(baseUrlLocal + '/book/image/'+isbn)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
    document.getElementById('imgSource')
    .setAttribute(
    'src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + 
 btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(response.data))) +"'"
);

    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="card-body" id="image-src">
      <img id="imgSource" src="" alt="Red dot" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in node.js

```
    document.getElementById('imgSource')
    .setAttribute(
    'src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + 
 btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(response.data))) +"'"
);
```

document object is available in your browser mate. In node js you can't just use this like that. If you want to render the image you have processed, then you might want to look for a front end template engine
like

- ejs
- pug
- handlebars

since ejs's syntax is a little bit annoying and can be very confusing sometimes you  can use an alternative like handlebars take a look at [here](https://handlebarsjs.com)
handle bars is like a template engine. If you are familiar with Laravel or ASP.NET's Razor blade or Angular's string interpolation techniques this is very much like that so

go to your shell and install handlebars like this

> npm install --save handlebars

since this is a little too much of a topic to discuss as an answer I'll just provide you with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1srD3Mdvf50) link a tutorial on how to install and use handle bars. try that mate you will be able to achieve what you are looking for.. Cheers ...